# How to pass array as varbinary in mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to pass an array as a varbinary parameter to a ms sql stored procedure using php. I am not sure how to convert an array into a varbinary or equivalent.

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot store the native type / get a representation of if AFAIK, most probably, you just want to `serialize` on save, and `unserialize` on retrieving.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, and finally got it to pass in using pack(), but I had issues with the stored procedure and converting the varbinary to a GUID, so I just took a ocmpletely different approach all together.

Comment: Ack, pack works for more efficient storage, depends on whether the overhead of unpack works or not (and what other languages may be working on the field).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or newer now you should utilize the **varbinary** data type.

If you are on an older version then put it into a varchar(max) column and use the below tSQL to convert it from a string back to hex:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @BinaryValue    [varbinary](256) ,
        @x              [xml]

SET @x = '<root></root>;'

SET @BinaryValue = 0x0200CDDBC2A60A08B57EDF7622CA52A45EC3BC234CE6A0F7D038F3BAE0EC00

SELECT  N'0x' + @x.value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@BinaryValue"))',
                         '[varchar](512)')

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
GO
```